# Is there a way to tell if an app has been added from Chrome Web Store?

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to display a message & install-button to the user if he did not yet install my drive app from Chrome Web Store.

Is there a way to tell if the app has been installed?

I can already access the list of apps, but I don't find a way to distinguish whether the user can create files from the Drive "Create"-menu and see my file icons or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve this information by sending an authorized `GET` request to the [`drive.about.get`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about/get) endpoint. The returned metadata will include a [`isCurrentAppInstalled`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about#isCurrentAppInstalled) attribute set to `true` if your app has been installed by the user:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/about
Authorization: Bearer *********
```

Comment: Wow, that was simple - how could I have missed that. Thanks a lot Alain!